# alternative way to define a function inside a class method

Tags: pandas, oop, class-method, python-class, pandas-styles

I have a the following class:

```
class Analysis():
    def __init__(self, file_dir):
        self.path = file_dir #file path directory 
    
    def getData(self):
        return pd.read_csv(self.path) # create a pandas dataframe 
    
    def getStd(self):
        return self.getData().loc['1':'5'].apply(lambda x: x.std()) # cacluate the standard deviation of all columns
    
    
    def getHighlight(self):
        
        #a function to highlight df based on the given condition 

        def highlight(x):
            c1 = 'background-color:red'
            c2 = 'background-color:yellow'
            c3 = 'background-color:green'
            
            #rows over which the highlighting function should apply 
            r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
            
            #first boolean mask for selecting the df elements 
            m1 = (x.loc[r]>x.loc['USL']) | (x.loc[r]<x.loc['LSL'])
            
            #second boolean mask for selecting the df elements 
            m2 = (x.loc[r]==x.loc['USL']) | (x.loc[r]==x.loc['LSL'])
     
            #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
            df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
            #modify values of df1 columns by boolean mask
            df1.loc[r, :] = np.select([m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3)
            
            return df1
        
        
        #apply the highlight function on the df to get highlighted 
        return self.getData().style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

`getData` method returns the df like this:

```
my_analysis = Analysis(path_to_file)
my_analysis.getData()

     A-A     A-B    A-C     A-D      A-E
Tg  0.37    10.24   5.02    0.63    20.30
USL 0.39    10.26   5.04    0.65    20.32
LSL 0.35    10.22   5.00    0.63    20.28
1   0.35    10.23   5.05    0.65    20.45
2   0.36    10.19   5.07    0.67    20.25
3   0.34    10.25   5.03    0.66    20.33
4   0.35    10.20   5.08    0.69    20.22
5   0.33    10.17   5.05    0.62    20.40
Max 0.36    10.25   5.08    0.69    20.45
Min 0.33    10.17   5.03    0.62    20.22
```

The `getHighligt method` has an inner function which applies to the df in order to highlight the df elements based on the given mask and it would out put something like this:

```
my_analysis.getHighlight()
```

[image]

My question is what is the pythonic or elegant way of defining the inner function inside the class method?

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with this set up. It's arguably the "correct" way to define a nested function. If I were being nitpicky I would say that the function should be defined outside of the class entirely since `highlight` does not use any class attributes and style apply is going to pass all of the necessary information to whatever function you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** the following remarks represent my opinion about the topic of pythonic code.

### Avoid Inner Functions

You should avoid inner functions at all cost. Sometimes they're necessary, but most of the time they're an indication that you might want to refactor your code.

### Avoid re-reading multiple times

I would also avoid calling `pd.read_csv` every time I want to perform some operation in the data. Unless there's a good reason to read the file over and over again, It's more performant to read it once and store it in a class attribute, or property.

### PEP-8 Naming Conventions

Another important thing to consider, if you're trying to make your code more pythonic, is to try to follow the [PEP8 naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), unless you're working on legacy code that does not follow PEP-8.

### Class Overkill

Finally, I think that creating a class for what you're doing seems a little overkill. Most of your methods are simply transformations that could be easily converted to functions. Aside from making your code less complex, It would improve its reusability.

### How I would write the `Analysis` class

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, annotations

from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Collection, Iterable, Type, Union

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes import ExtensionDtype  # type: ignore

# Custom types for type hinting
Axes = Collection[Any]
NpDtype = Union[
    str, np.dtype, Type[Union[str, float, int, complex, bool, object]]
]
Dtype = Union["ExtensionDtype", NpDtype]


# Auxiliary functions
def is_iterable_not_string(iterable: Any) -> bool:
    """Return True, if `iterable` is an iterable object, and not a string.

    Parameters
    ----------
    iterable: Any
        The object to check whether it's an iterable except for strings,
        or not.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True, if object is iterable, but not a string.
        Otherwise, if object isn't an iterable, or if it's a string, return
        False.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> class FakeIterable(int):
    ...     def __iter__(self): pass
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string('abcde'))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(bytes(12345)))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(12345))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(123.45))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(type))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(list))  # Type list isn't iterable
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(object))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(None))
    False
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(list()))  # Empty list is still iterable
    True
    >>> # `FakeIterable` has a method `__iter__`, therefore it's considered
    >>> # iterable, even though it isn't.
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(FakeIterable(10)))
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(list('abcde')))
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(tuple('abcde')))
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(set('abcde')))
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(np.array(list('abcdef'))))
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string({col: [1, 2, 3, 4] for col in 'abcde'}))
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(
    ...     pd.DataFrame({col: [1, 2, 3, 4] for col in 'abcde'}))
    ... )
    True
    >>> print(is_iterable_not_string(pd.DataFrame()))
    True

    Notes
    -----
    In python, any object that contains a method called `__iter__` considered
    an “iterable”. This means that you can, in theory, fake an “iterable”
    object, by creating a method called `__iter__` that doesn't contain any
    real implementation. For a concrete case, see the examples section.

    Python common iterable objects:

        - strings
        - bytes
        - lists
        - tuples
        - sets
        - dictionaries

    Python common non-iterable objects:

        - integers
        - floats
        - None
        - types
        - objects

    """
    return (not isinstance(iterable, (bytes, str))
            and isinstance(iterable, Iterable))


def prepare_dict(data: dict) -> dict:
    """Transform non-iterable dictionary values into lists.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : dict
        The dictionary to convert non-iterable values into lists.

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Dictionary with non-iterable values converted to lists.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> d = {'a': '1', 'b': 2}
    >>> prepare_dict(d)
    {'a': ['1'], 'b': [2]}
    >>> pd.DataFrame(d) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
    >>> pd.DataFrame(prepare_dict(d))
       a  b
    0  1  2

    Notes
    -----
    Use this function to prepare dictionaries, before calling
    `pandas.DataFrame`, to make sure all values have the correct format.
    """
    return {
        key: value if is_iterable_not_string(value) else [value]
        for key, value in data.items()
    }


def check_dict_value_lens(data: dict) -> bool:
    """Check whether all values from dictionary have the same lenght.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : dict
        The dictionary to check the values lenghts.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True, if all `data` values have the same lenght. False otherwise.
    """
    min_len = min(map(lambda value: len(value), data.values()))
    return all(len(value) == min_len for value in data.values())


def read_file(path: Path | str, **kwargs: Any) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Read a DataFrame from a file.

    Supported file types are:
        - `.csv`
        - `.xlsx`, `.xls`, `.xlsm`, `.xlsb` (Excel files)
        - `.json`
        - `.parquet`
        - `.feather`
        - `.html`

    Parameters
    ----------
    path : Path | str
        The path to the file.
    kwargs : Any
        Keyword arguments to pass to pandas io functions.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        The DataFrame read from the file.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If the file type not supported.
    FileNotFoundError
        If the file doesn't exist.
    """
    _path = Path(path)
    path = str(path)

    if not _path.is_file():
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"File {path} does not exist.")
    if _path.suffix in [".csv", ".txt"]:
        return pd.read_csv(path, **kwargs)
    if ".xls" in _path.suffix:
        return pd.read_excel(path, **kwargs)
    if _path.suffix == ".json":
        return pd.read_json(path, **kwargs)
    if _path.suffix == ".pickle":
        return pd.read_pickle(path, **kwargs)
    if _path.suffix == ".html":
        return pd.read_html(path, **kwargs)
    if _path.suffix == ".feather":
        return pd.read_feather(path, **kwargs)
    if _path.suffix in [".parquet", ".pq"]:
        return pd.read_parquet(path, **kwargs)
    raise ValueError(f"File {path} has an unknown extension.")


def highlight(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Highlight a DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        The DataFrame to highlight. Required indexes:
            - ["USL", "LSL", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        The DataFrame with highlighted rows.
    """
    # The dataframe cells background colors.
    c1: str = "background-color:red"
    c2: str = "background-color:yellow"
    c3: str = "background-color:green"

    # Rows over which the highlighting function should apply
    rows: list[str] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    # First boolean mask for selecting the df elements
    m1 = (df.loc[rows] > df.loc["USL"]) | (df.loc[rows] < df.loc["LSL"])

    # Second boolean mask for selecting the df elements
    m2 = (df.loc[rows] == df.loc["USL"]) | (df.loc[rows] == df.loc["LSL"])

    # DataFrame with same index, and column names as the original,
    # but with filled empty strings.
    df_highlight = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

    # Change values of df1 columns by boolean mask
    df_highlight.loc[rows, :] = np.select(
        [m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3
    )

    return df_highlight


class Analysis:
    """
    Read a dataframe, and help performing some analysis in the data.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path_or_data : str | Path | pd.DataFrame
        The path to a file, or a dataframe to analyze.

    Attributes
    ----------
    _data : pd.DataFrame
        The data read from the file.
    _path : str | Path
        The path to the file.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> data = {
    ...     'A-A': [
    ...           0.37, 0.39, 0.35, 0.35, 0.36, 0.34, 0.35, 0.33, 0.36, 0.33,
    ...     ],
    ...     'A-B': [
    ...           10.24, 10.26, 10.22, 10.23, 10.19, 10.25, 10.2, 10.17, 10.25,
    ...           10.17,
    ...      ],
    ...     'A-C': [
    ...           5.02, 5.04, 5.0, 5.05, 5.07, 5.03, 5.08, 5.05, 5.08, 5.03,
    ...     ],
    ...     'A-D': [
    ...           0.63, 0.65, 0.63, 0.65, 0.67, 0.66, 0.69, 0.62, 0.69, 0.62,
    ...     ],
    ...     'A-E': [
    ...           20.3, 20.32, 20.28, 20.45, 20.25, 20.33, 20.22, 20.4,
    ...           20.45, 20.22,
    ...      ],
    ... }
    >>> index = ['Tg', 'USL', 'LSL', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'Max', 'Min']
    >>> analysis = Analysis.from_dict(data, index=index)
    >>> analysis.get_std()
    A-A    0.011402
    A-B    0.031937
    A-C    0.019494
    A-D    0.025884
    A-E    0.097211
    dtype: float64
    """

    _path: Path | str | None = None
    _data: pd.DataFrame | None = None

    @property
    def path(self) -> str | Path:
        """Get the path to the file.

        Returns
        -------
        str | Path
            The path to the file.

        Raises
        ------
        ValueError
            If `_path` is `None`.
        """
        if self._path is None:
            raise ValueError("Path not set.")
        return str(self._path)

    @path.setter
    def path(self, path: str | Path):
        """Set the path of the file to analyze.

        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str | Path
            The path of the file to analyze.
            Path should point to a `.csv` file.

        Raises
        ------
        FileNotFoundError
            If the path not found.
        """
        _path = Path(path)
        if _path.is_file():
            self._path = str(path)
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Path {path} does not exist.")

    @property
    def data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """Dataframe read from `path`.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DataFrame
            The dataframe read from `path`.
        """
        if self._data is None:
            self._data = self.get_data()
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, data: pd.DataFrame):
        """Set the data to analyze.

        Parameters
        ----------
        data : pd.DataFrame
            The data to analyze.
        """
        self._data = data

    def __init__(self, path_or_data: str | Path | pd.DataFrame):
        """Initialize the Analyzer.

        Parameters
        ----------
        path_or_data : str | Path | pd.DataFrame
            The path to a file, or a dataframe to analyze.

        Raises
        ------
        ValueError
            If `path_or_data` not a `str`, `Path`, or `pd.DataFrame`.
        """
        if isinstance(path_or_data, (str, Path)):
            self.path = path_or_data
        elif isinstance(path_or_data, pd.DataFrame):
            self.data = path_or_data
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid type {type(path_or_data)}.")

    def get_data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """Read the data from the file.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DataFrame
            The dataframe read from the `path` property.
        """
        return read_file(self.path)

    def get_std(self) -> pd.Series:
        """Calcuate the standard deviation of every column.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Series
            The standard deviation of every column.
        """
        return self.data.loc["1":"5"].apply(lambda x: x.std())  # type: ignore

    def highlight_frame(
        self, round_values: int | None = None
    ) -> pd.io.formats.style.Styler:  # type: ignore
        """Highlight dataframe, based on some condition.

        Parameters
        ----------
        round_values: int | None
            If defined, sets the precision of the Styler object with the
            highlighted dataframe.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.io.formats.style.Styler
            The Styler object with the highlighted dataframe.
        """
        highlight_df = self.data.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
        if isinstance(round_values, int) and round_values >= 0:
            return highlight_df.format(precision=round_values)
        return highlight_df

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(
        cls,
        data: dict,
        index: Axes | None = None,
        columns: Axes | None = None,
        dtype: Dtype | None = None,
    ) -> Analysis:
        """Create an Analysis object from a dictionary.

        Parameters
        ----------
        data : dict
            The dictionary to create the Analysis object from.
        index : Index or array-like
            Index to use for resulting frame. Defaults to RangeIndex, if
            no indexing information part of input data and no index provided.
        columns : Index or array-like
            Column labels to use for resulting frame when data doesn't have
            them, defaulting to RangeIndex(0, 1, 2, ..., n).
            If data contains column labels, will perform column selection
            instead.
        dtype : dtype, default None
            Data type to force. Only a single dtype allowed. If None, infer.

        Returns
        -------
        Analysis
            An instance of the `Analysis` class.

        Raises
        ------
        ValueError
            If dictionary values have different lenghts.
        """
        data = prepare_dict(data)
        if check_dict_value_lens(data):
            return cls(
                pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
            )
        raise ValueError(
            f"Dictionary values don't have the same lenghts.\nData: {data}"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```